# i want to use a external font, but doesn't seem to be in effect

Tags: css, font-face

i want to use a external font, but doesn't seem to be in effect

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "FZFangSong-Z02S";
    src: url("../fonts/fzfsjw.eot"),/* IE9*/
         url("../fonts/fzfsjw.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
         url("../fonts/fzfsjw.woff") format("woff"),
         url("../fonts/fzfsjw.ttf") format("truetype"),
         url("../fonts/fzfsjw.svg") format("svg");/* iOS 4.1- */
}
```

here is my documents map

[image]

i used inline style

```
<p style="font-family: FZFangSong-Z02S;"></p>
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Are you sure that the font files exist inside the `[one_level_up]/fonts/` local directory?

Comment: where is your css file where you declare `font-face` - give a path please

Comment: @hunzaboy No...

Comment: Are you referencing the style on any elements? E.g. `body { font-family: FZFangSong-Z02S; }`?

Comment: only thing that could be is that you didn't include your fonts css file in html

Comment: @ChristosLytras yes

Comment: @MattBaker yes I used inline style

Comment: Open your console > go to Network tab, set your filter on Font.  (Here's how: https://www.screencast.com/t/YtFJyUtWC). Is your status code 200, is your path is correct?

Comment: @Mahmoud i did.  No font file was loaded

Comment: so possibly to forgot referencing the stylesheet in you html file

Comment: @sTx thanks anyway